# Cannot make StyleCop errors appear as build errors (rather than warnings)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, bamboo, stylecop

I am trying to get builds to fail if they do not pass StyleCop. Currently, these are only being displayed as warnings. I have tried to follow [the documentation here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setting%20Up%20StyleCop%20MSBuild%20Integration).

I have added to my CSProj file `<Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />` which seems to correctly include StyleCop.

Then, I added the `StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings` set to false in my csproj file. Here is the start of my CSProj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.Targets" />  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
```

This causes, in Bamboo (my continuous integration server) warnings to appear, but no errors. The same occurs in Visual Studio.

Why are StyleCop errors still appearing as warnings?

Comment: Is it possible that the $(StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings) is being overridden on the MSBuild command line? If you can run your build with diagnostics on it would allow you to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to move the stylecop import after the C# import line.
Also you need to add the StyleCopEnabled = true property in the csproj file